# Cookies: Sent in request even after all have been deleted

Tags: cookies

I am confused about how cookies are set. It seems that cookies can be sent in the request header, even after I have deleted them all.

What I do:

1. In IE: delete all cookies (wrench-thing->safety->delete browsing history-> check all, except preserve favorites-> Delete)
2. Go to random site (google.com) and open the Network tab (F12/Network) - because it won't open from blank tab.
3. Make sure browsing history persists (tools-> clear entries on navigate-> uncheck both)
4. Click "Start capturing"
5. Go to site: http://www.klm.com/travel/dk_da/index.htm
6. Look at Network data. For the first url (http://www.klm.com/travel/dk_da/index.htm   ), click "Go to detailed view". Click "cookies"

I look at the cookie that is being sent (in Cookies tab or under 'Request headers') and it's already sending 7 values, for example, EBT_JSESSIONID. But, where do these values come from? I haven't received anything at this point. I realize that cookies can be set via javascript, but I haven't loaded any js at this point either.

I am trying to figure this out as part of webscrabing. Really want to be able to do it without Selenium or the like, and need to generate/use the various IDs that are being passed around the various calls.

Comment: Per-session cookies aren't cleared until you close the browser.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be it.

Answer (score 0):

Using chrome in Mac we had this issue and restarting the browser did solve the issue. The scenario was weird because the value was being sent only for one specific HTML.